# Have a column in datatables.js automatically selected

Tags: javascript, datatables

This is I believe an easy question.

I have a datatable being used in my application, it has a column called "Customer Name" I am trying to have the config for the table done in such was a that a Column name will be automatically selected to display the name of our customers in order as soon as the table loads.

I have not been able to find exactly how (but managed to find solutions to other problems while looking at the docs) to give a better graphic description, this is the table:

[image]

See how Inventory Code has the blue arrow automatically selected? How can I make it towards Customer Name being automatically selected instead?

Sorry if this is too basic, I have not found it in the docs, probably been looking in the wrong place, if someone could point me to the correct doc info I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Default ordering (sorting)](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
       "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
   });
});
```

Where `1` stands for the 2 columns here called "Customer Name", as order option is based on zero index. By, default datatable are sorted by 1st column in `asc` order.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks man! Lemme just check the docs again to see where I missed that. Cheers!